# Static class to get connections from connection pool

Tags: java, database-connection, connection-pool

I want to understand the concepts of connection pool.For example I have the following xml file in META-INF with my DB settings

```
 <Resource name="jdbc/appname"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              maxActive="100" 
              maxIdle="30"
              maxWait="10000"
              minIdle="10"
              username="postgres" 
              password="123"
              driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
              url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Lab4"/>
```

To use connection pool I use the folliwng class

```
    public class DataBaseConnection {

        private static DataSource dataSource;

        static {
            try {
                InitialContext initContext = new InitialContext();
                dataSource = (DataSource) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/appname");
            } catch (NamingException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }

        public static Connection getConnection() {
            try {
                return dataSource.getConnection();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }
```

This is the usage

```
public class UserQueries{ 
 public User selectUserByLoginAndPassword(final String login, final String password) {
        try(Connection connection=DataBaseConnection.getConnection())
        try (PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement(SELECT_QUERY)) {
            st.setString(1, login);
            st.setString(2, password);
            ResultSet result = st.executeQuery();
            while (result.next()) {
                final User user = User.newBuilder()
                        .setId(result.getInt("id"))
                        .setAge(result.getInt("age"))
                        .setName(result.getString("name"))
                        .setPassword(result.getString("password"))
                        .setLogin(login)
                        .build();
                return user;

            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
        throw new NullPointerException("Nu such user in db");
    }

   }
```

The question is, if i modify DataBaseConnection in the following way,

```
public class DataBaseConnection {

        private  DataSource dataSource;

        public DataBaseConnection()
            try {
                InitialContext initContext = new InitialContext();
                dataSource = (DataSource) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/appname");
            } catch (NamingException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);                
        }

        public  Connection getConnection() {
            try {
                return dataSource.getConnection();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }
```

And i will create new DataBaseConnection object in each class that use db conections, does it mean that each class(for example UserQueries) will create separates conection pool to use?

Example

```
public class UserQueries{ 
  private DataBaseConnection dbCon = new DataBaseConnection();
 public User selectUserByLoginAndPassword(final String login, final String password) {
        try(Connection connection = dbCon.getConnection())
        try (PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement(SELECT_QUERY)) {
            st.setString(1, login);
            st.setString(2, password);
            ResultSet result = st.executeQuery();
            while (result.next()) {
                final User user = User.newBuilder()
                        .setId(result.getInt("id"))
                        .setAge(result.getInt("age"))
                        .setName(result.getString("name"))
                        .setPassword(result.getString("password"))
                        .setLogin(login)
                        .build();
                return user;

            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
        throw new NullPointerException("Nu such user in db");
    }

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each JNDI lookup returns a new instance of `DataSource`. Each `DataSource` instance maintains it's own pool of connections.

See tomcat implementation of `Datasource.getConnection()` below:,

```
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    if (pool == null)
        return createPool().getConnection();
    return pool.getConnection();
}
```

And this creates the `connectionPool`:

```
private synchronized ConnectionPool pCreatePool() throws SQLException {
    if (pool != null) {
        return pool;
    } else {
        pool = new ConnectionPool(poolProperties);
        return pool;
    }
}
```

In summary,

- New `DataSource` instance is returned for every JNDI lookup.
- New connection pool will be created for every instance of `DataSource`

Comment: Does it mean that using static DataSource guarantee that my applcation will use the only one connection pool?

Comment: Better put: Using a single `DataSource` instance is the advisable way. "...my applcation will use the only one connection pool?" _-- Yes._